# Testing Google Play Campaign Measurement

Tags: android, eclipse, google-analytics

I am having some problems with testing the install_referrer of my app, before publishing it on Google Play Store. These are the steps I did. So if you find any error or miss, let me know!

Below is Updated Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<service android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingService" />
<receiver android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver" android:exported="true" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

after that I create the /res/analytics.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>     
 <resources> 
    <string name="ga_trackingId">TRACKING ID FROM GOOGLE ANALYTICS ACCOUNT<string>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true </bool>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
 </resources>
```

added to my MainActivity File these 2 methods:

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);  // Add this method.
  }    
 @Override
    public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);  // Add this method.
  }
```

then (I'm working on Ubuntu) I opened the terminal (i think the error is here):

```
PATH_ADB_TOOL shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER
         -n MY_PACKAGE_NAME/com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver--es "referrer"
         "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

after that, It says:

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER pkg=referrer cmp=MY_PACKAGE_NAME/com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver--es }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

and when I launch my app from Eclipse to my Nexus 7, I found in logcat this:

```
05-22 11:05:39.461: W/GAV2(15255): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), will retry.
05-22 11:05:39.461: W/ActivityManager(515): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) } U=0: not found
05-22 11:05:39.471: I/GAV2(15255): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
```

**EDIT**

Finally it worked. The problem was so silly: since I am using Eclipse, I thought I'd just plugin the device on which I was going to install the app and debug the Android project, for then closing the app from the device.

My fault: I had to install the app vi ADB INSTALL, then launching it from the device and check the logcat on Eclipse.

On Google tutorial it says:

> If the campaign data was received properly, you can expect to see the SDK print a debug message using logcat similar to this one:

```
Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Campaign found: utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign
```

but I got:

```
05-24 14:42:19.303: I/GAV3(30436): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Campaign found: utm_source=testSource
```

it says **SIMILAR**, but I was asking myself, why it is not the same.. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it says SIMILAR, but I was asking myself, why it is not the same... Anyone can help me?

You must [URL encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) your referrer string. In particular you have to replace all your ampersands (&) with `%26`.

You can also use the [campaign measurement URL generator](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#google-play-url-builder) and then copy everything after `referrer=` and use that as the referrer you use with adb.